# Any reason to use web server (Express) within Electron app?

Tags: express, electron

I'm learning Electron and everything I'm seeing is using the file:// protocol to load pages, and so far this is working fine.  I also see some references to using Express within Electron.

My question is - is there any reason to use a web server such as Express within an Electron app?  What does it get you?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the scenario is pretty odd: The combination of a desktop-UI with a server-framework seems to be somewhat counter-intuitive.

What you see when file:// is referenced are (local) file system calls - these could well be calls to other protocols like http:// or ws:// instead, and do not require the Express framework to be present.

Instead, Express enables your application to receive connections from the outside and act as a server. This could be a webserver serving static or dynamic content, a REST-API endpoint or some other kind of web service endpoint.

[There is indeed a project showing exactly this combination](https://github.com/frankhale/electron-with-express): The Express server is responsible for serving content, Electron is used to wrap a logging-UI that displays whatever is currently happening.

From an architecturial standpoint however, I would probably seperate each of these concerns into seperate standalone applications.

Comment: Thanks, Jens.  I get the client/server distinction.  Are you saying that within Electron I can use http *without* express?  I'm not aware of any benefit to doing so, but that's kinda the crux of my question...am I missing some benefit to using http:// over file:// ?

Comment: The file:// call will always be a call *from* the Electron application to some file in the system, while using Express will enable http calls *to* the Electron application from outside the scope of the application itself (using other clients, like browsers)

Comment: Can you explain more why it is somewhat counter-intuitive?

Comment: There are absolutely valid use-cases for using express and electron alongside each other. For simple apps it's absolutely not necessary, but it may improve re-usability for more complex apps.

* Electron for desktop UI, Express for existing backend API
* Companion desktop app for Express-powered site
* Add Express APIs to enhance Electron app functionality
* Share UI code between Electron and Express-served web version

The key distinction is separating the UI layer from the API/server layer.

Answer (score 2):

I was considering this since I'm making an Offline Desktop Electron app and wanted to make some reusable functions for an app that could be a new SaaS solution.

So unless you were thinking of the same, then I don't really find any good reason to have this. I'm trying to find some best practices, but I found little to none. It seems the practice was quite uncommon although totally possible. Technically, all you have to do is use the Electron as a server.

At first, I tried out ExpressJS just to make sure whether the express app could run, the only problem I had was with `cors`, but things went well after that. What I can see is, that if you're planning to create a desktop app, and it was about to go complex, you should just go to your usual web library/framework tools to make it easier.

But hey, I'm open to suggestions if I made a mistake okay. I'm trying out this myself. I'll update anytime if I found the cons of it.